# Apache 2 PHP "not found or unable to stat" crashes our site

Tags: php, apache, brute-force

Our server started to get hit with a particular URL from many different IPs. The URL was for the file wp-login.php. We are running PHP but we are not running Word Press. This looks like some sort of brute force attack. We have thousands of error log entries that look like this:

[Mon Sep 25 08:49:02.199784 2017] [:error] [pid 55904] [client 85.101.234.119:62848] script '/var/www/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Sep 25 08:52:59.426923 2017] [:error] [pid 62559] [client 157.50.13.248:57481] script '/var/www/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Sep 25 08:59:24.561571 2017] [:error] [pid 73252] [client 42.115.49.147:39332] script '/var/www/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Sep 25 09:03:36.470029 2017] [:error] [pid 74502] [client 24.14.179.217:34758] script '/var/www/html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat

Eventually we get the following error log entry:

[Tue Sep 26 07:31:04.925077 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 53301] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

Then we start getting thousands of these entries:

[Tue Sep 26 07:40:26.028058 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61097 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:27.032093 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61118 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:28.032829 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 53301] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:38.034664 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61127 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:38.035026 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61116 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:38.035068 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61115 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:39.499756 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 53301] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:49.501294 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 73499 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:49.501632 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 73498 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:49.501667 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 73500 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:49.501764 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61188 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:49.501797 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61170 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:40:50.509833 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 53301] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Sep 26 07:41:00.512913 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 53301] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Sep 26 07:41:10.529013 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61268 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:41:10.535317 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61201 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Sep 26 07:41:10.535367 2017] [core:notice] [pid 53301] AH00051: child pid 61204 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Then we have literally 100 or more apache2 processes running and our swap space maxes out and the server comes to a crawl and is unresponsive.

I temporarily fixed it by putting a blank wp-login.php page in the root and restarting apache. But now I can reproduce the same behavior by simply making a request to a bogus URL. I get a 404 but I also get more apache2 processes running and the same log entries.

I don’t know very much about Apache and it’s configuration. Is there anyone that can help me with this issue ?

Thanks,

Warren

Comment: I think you could have a better help at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: One strategy would be to see the access log file of apache, get the IP attackers and add a DROP rule for then on your iptables

Comment: PSAD, at the minimum. Every one should be running security software on their server.

Comment: There are literally thousands of different IP addresses coming from all over the world. Some sort of bot army of infected PCs.

Comment: @JorgeCampos playing whack-a-mole with botnets is futile, and this one is just looking for more vulnerable WP installs to zombify. If you're not running WordPress then just write a rule to 403 all requests to `wp-login.php` and anything else WordPress-ish.

Comment: @Sammitch I prefer to think "you never know" so, better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Warren then don't use that strategy, because you will end up blocking some ISP IP and potentially your own users... So do as rtfm said, use a software to inspect your server